# Azure AD B2C tenant deletion fails

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, aad-b2c

I can't delete my B2C directory.

I've followed the instructions at [How do I delete my Azure AD B2C tenant?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga#how-do-i-delete-my-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-)
 fails, even though all Resource Status's are green.

I've purged all applications, signed into the tenant with the CLI and done an `az ad app list` which returns an empty array.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, this is due to a remaining Enterprise Application being enabled for login.

To fix:

1. Switch into the B2C tenant then go to Azure Active Directory (type AAD into the resources search box).
2. Select **Enterprise Applications** on the left navigation
3. Select each application in turn then go to Properties
4. Change **Enabled for users to sign-in?** to **No**
5. Save

Then follow the normal instructions to delete the tenant.

[image]

Comment: how did you get this trick? I confirm it works.

Comment: I don't have any enterprise applications...